Using signal to clean up process
I am learning how to use signals. I created a small program that connects to a database and prints the results.  I am leaving the database connection open.  I am sending a SIGTERM to end the program.  That works.  But when I try to add my database disconnect object it fails.  I made db global.  Any help or explanation of what I am doing incorrectly. My plan to to clean up socket connections and others to shut the program down gracefully.
global db
def term_handler(signum,frame):
    print('In term handler')
    db.disconnect()
    #more clean up to come.
    sys.exit()

def main():
   db = connection
   results = db.select('query here')
   print(results.fetchall())
   #db.disconnect()
   # The above disconnect works when in main.  but fails when in term_handler

  signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM,term_handler)

  while True:
      print('yes')
      sleep(2)
  return None
if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()


How is it failing? Where do you set the connection variable? Is that a placeholder for the code that actually connects to the DB?

the global directive needs to be in the function that assigns the variable, not at top-level. So you need to put global db in the main() function.

@Barmar connection is placeholder for the connection code. Moving ‘global’ into ‘main’ worked.
